# Neo4j Browser : impossible to create a new database

Tags: neo4j

I've been using Neo4j Developer (3.3.2) for a few weeks now in order to create a POC: I must admit it's terrific !

I tried a few days ago to create a new (local) database under 3.3.3, unfortunately, I never succeeded. After a few uninstall/install/delete/update/3.3.3/3.3.2/.

What I'm doing :

- Click on "New Graph"
- Then "Create a Local Graph"
- Set Name/Password
- Version : 3.3.3 or 3.3.2 (same result)
- Finally click "Create"

The result is the message "Creating a new database..." is displayed infinitely.

Image Example : [Neo4j Creating Database Trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95YoN.png)

Comment: try creating the db via command line